# Can't export into fbx file

Tags: export, .fbx

i'm making a racing game and i made this cool F1 car, i ran it at first walf way trough the work it worked. But then i applied the subdivision surface and it gave me a big error (i did twice and each time blender was the problem) so i tried to export it as an .fbx file but it showed me this error. How can i fix it ?[image]

Comment: Don't use FBX format if you do not absolutely have to. Use another format.

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys What? Why? FBX is the best exchange format for GE there is. Does the car have at least one UV Map?

Comment: It is a proprietary file format and as far as I know the license of it's SDK is not compatible with Blender's license and that makes it difficult to support well in Blender. It does not work very well in Blender, not all of the features are supported. I think it's a good idea to look for alternatives to FBX whenever possible if you work with Blender.